# Swift : What is the equivalent of regions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, swift, xcode

I'm used to code android applications, and I'm starting in Apple development. In Android studio, it's possible to surround a bloc of code within a region, like this :

```java
//region VARIABLES
int a;
float b;
//endregion
```

for a better visualization of the code.

Is there an equivalent in Swift? Or is the closest thing to it is :

```swift
// MARK: - VARIABLES
var a:String
var b:String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I believe `// MARK:` is the closest equivalent in Swift.

It isn't a direct equivalent, but you can also break up the methods in your classes using extensions. Example

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // The main body of the view controller goes here
}


extension MyViewController {
   // View controller lifecycle methods
}

extension MyViewController {
   // Table view delegate methods
}

extension MyViewController {
   // Table view data source methods
}
```

(And you can use that in combination with `// MARK:` tags.)